# How PHP co-routines / generators works

Tags: php, generator, yield, coroutine

I've found this example of PHP co-routine.

https://gnugat.github.io/2014/04/30/php-generators-and-coroutines.html

```
function holy_grail_countdown($number)
{
    while (0 < $number) {
        $reset = (yield $number);
        $number = $reset ?: $number - 1;
    }
}

$c = holy_grail_countdown(5);
foreach ($c as $number) {
    echo "$number\n"; // outputs 5, then 2 and finally 1.
    if (5 === $number) {
        $c->send(3);
    }
}
```

I still don't get why it's working. Why it does not output 5, 3, 2, 1?

It sends value 3 into expressions (`(yield $number)`), but it looks like it perform 2 iterations.

```
# 1st iteration
$reset = (yield $number); # reset=3
$number = $reset ?: $number - 1; = #number=3
# 2nd iteration
$reset = (yield $number); # reset=null
$number = $reset ?: $number - 1; = #number=3-1=>2
```

Why is there 2nd iteration with `reset=null`?

Thank you.

Comment: Because each iteration of the foreach loop always sends a null to the generator to ensure that it is non-blocking in case your code doesn't send any value into the generator when it is expecting a value

Comment: Oh, thank you. So basically, it perform 1 or 2 interations according to if I send data or not. It's clever. 

Is there any usecase to handle the `null` iteration?